# String with accentuation is missing from list inside for loop

Tags: python

**EDIT:** For newcomers, the problem has nothing to do with accentuation, but slicing.

---

I have this list of strings that the last item is a string with accents, I cant iterate through it! Look the example:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> A = "I have no accents."
>>> B = "I dó hávé álót óf áccénts."
>>> dummy = "me dumb"

>>> list = [dummy, A, B]
>>> print list
['me dumb', 'I have no accents.', 'I d\xc3\xb3 h\xc3\xa1v\xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa1l\xc3\xb3t \xc3\xb3f \xc3\xa1cc\xc3\xa9nts.']

>>> for entry in list[1:-1]:
...     print entry;
... 
I have no accents.
>>>
```

Comment: `list[1:-1]` and what did you expect?

Comment: You are not iterating over *any* strings with accents. You sliced the list to exclude the first and last element instead.

Comment: Really? The last? How to slice from the second to the last?

Comment: @fanl I edited my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can't iterate through it, **you are explicitly excluding it**.

Try:

```
for entry in list:  # Without slicing.
```

This is because `[1:-1]` basically means *'from the second element up to and not including the final element'*- in your case that sections contains just one item.

---

**EDIT:**

To go from second through to the last, just do:

```
for item in list[1:]
```

Comment: Ok, works, but I need to slice it. I must skip the first element. What's the rationale behind the iteration working without slicing?

Comment: @fanl You were on the right track, but with slicing, the end argument is not included in the slice, even though the start is. To go for the first element onwards, just do `list[1:]`. Oh and don't use `list` as a  name by the way, it shadows the builtin. Name it to something else such as `mylist`.

Comment: True, I messed up with slicing. Thanks.

Comment: @fanl Glad to help. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it with the tick after the grace period has passed? Thank you.